# Get Super Class In JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am making a class.

```js
class A {
    constructor() {
    }
    getThis() {
        return this;
    }
}
class B extends A {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.superclass = super;  // SyntaxError: 'super' keyword unexpected here
        this.superclass = super.getThis();  // this.superclass is this(B and not A)
    }
}
```

How can I access the super class (not the property or methods)?

---

Edit:

```js
class A {
    constructor() {
        this.a = 1;
    }
    getThis() {
        return this;
    }
}
class B extends A {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.b = 2;

        console.log( [get the super class] );  // A { a: 1 } 
        console.log(this);  // B { a: 1, b: 2 }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to get the super class with the data?

Comment: Re your edit: See the second and third parts of my answer. When you do `new B`, there is no separate instance of `A` created; just one object that's both an instance of `B` and an instance of `A` is created.

Comment: Do you just want to print out the name of the super class? what's your goal?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's rare that doing so is of any use to you, but there are a few ways when using `class` syntax:

You can get the prototype of `B`:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(B) === A // true
```

That works because `class` syntax assigns the `A` constructor function as the prototype of the `B` constructor function (which is handy, it means `B` inherits static methods from `A`).

Or you can do it by getting the `constructor` property of the prototype of `B.prototype`:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(B.prototype).constructor === A // true
```

Or if you want to use an instance of `B` as your starting point (`this` in this example):

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(this)).constructor === A // true
```

Live Example:

```js
class A {
    constructor() {
    }
}
class B extends A {
    constructor() {
        super();
        
        console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(B) === A); // true

        console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(B.prototype).constructor === A); // true

        // Or to get it from `this`:
        console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(this)).constructor === A); // true
    }
}

new B();
```

---

Your `getThis` suggests a misconception, though. When you do `new B` to create an instance of `B`, there **is not** a separate object created that's just an instance of `A`. The one object that `new B` creates is a combination of the features of `A` and `B` as a result of both inheritance and initialization. There is no separate `A` instance. (There is `A.prototype`, but that isn't an instance of `A`, it's just an object used as the prototype of instances of `A`.)

---

Re your edit:

> Is it possible to get the super class with the data?

I think you mean "Is it possible to get the *instance* of the super class with the data?" The answer is yes or no depending on how you want to look at it. An instance of `B` **is** an instance of `A`, so in that sense, "yes" because you already have it because you have an instance of `B`. But there is no separate instance of `A` that's **only** an `A` and not a `B` (see above), so in that sense, "no."

With the `A` and `B` in your edit, before doing `new B`, you have something like this in memory, basically the two constructor functions `A` and `B` and their associated `A.prototype` and `B.prototype` objects:

```
               +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
               |                                                       |
               v                                                       |
       +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                                               |
A−−−−−>| Function A    |  +−>Function.prototype                        |
       +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |                                            |
       | [[Prototype]] |−−+                                            |
       | name: "A"     |     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                         |
       | prototype     |−−−−>| A.prototype   |                         |
       +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                         |
               ^             | [[Prototype]] |−−−−−>Object.prototype   |
               |             | constructor   |−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
               |             +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
               +−−−−−−−−−−+          ^
                          |          |
       +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |          +−−−−−−−−−−+
B−−−−−>| Function B    |  |                     |
       +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |                     |
       | [[Prototype]] |−−+                     |
       | name: "B"     |     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
       | prototype     |−−−−>| B.prototype   |  |
       +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
               ^             | [[Prototype]] |−−+
               |             | constructor   |−−+
               |             +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
               |                                |
               +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

*(Some details omitted.)*

Now, if you do:

```
const b = new B();
```

that creates a **single** object. The `A` constructor adds an `a` property to that new object, and the `B` constructor adds a `b` property to that new object:

```
       +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
b−−−−−>| Instance of B |
       +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
       | [[Prototype]] |−−−−>B.prototype
       | a: 1          |
       | b: 2          |
       +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

It's a single object, not separate ones containing `a` and `b`. The `this` that `A`'s code uses in `this.a = 1` is the same object as the `this` that `B`'s code uses in `this.b = 2`.

Comment: FWIW, I go into `class` syntax and the exact object structures created in Chapter 4 of my recent book, *JavaScript: The New Toys*. Links in my profile if you're interested.

Comment: Nice answer so far. I'd also point out that `this.a = 1;` always creates an own property descriptor on the object instance itself rather than assigning to some property descriptor farther up the prototype chain, _even if the prototype chain has an existing descriptor_ (though that's not even the case in their example). Consider this code for example though: `class A { constructor() { this.a += 2; } }; A.prototype.a = 1; console.log(new A()); console.log(new A());` Each instance will have an own property `a: 3` while the prototype remains `a: 1`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - Good point (for data properties; accessors of course work differently). I'm doing up a diagram, I'll cover that off there.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - In the end, I thought it was a bit off-topic to the central theme of "it's one object." It's a useful thing for people to know, but separate, I think, to the point above. Thanks though. :-)

Comment: I would personally use `Object.getPrototypeOf(this.constructor)` instead of `Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(this)).constructor`. The latter one is kind of cryptic imo, while the first one says get the prototype of the constructor/class of the current instance.

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking shouldn't be necessary, I hope this answer can clarify that a bit

Here we see that you never need `return this` because a class constructor already returns itself by default:

```
class A {
    constructor(){
        // already returns this to the caller of `new`
    }
}

let a = new A()
console.log(a)   // logs the `this` scope of the A instance
```

If B extends A, then the resulting object contains the properties and methods of A and B combined. You can check that by doing `console.log(b)` . There is no A instance.

If B overwrites methods of A - making the original A method invisible, then you can still find them by using `super...`

```
class A {
   doSomething(){
     console.log("world")
   }
}

class B extends A {
  constructor() {
    super()
  }
  doSomething(){
    console.log("hello")
    super.doSomething()
  }
}

let b = new B()
b.doSomething() // logs: hello world
```

Not an exact answer to your question but maybe it's helpful anyway!